# How to get "max" attribute value of DefaultRolloverStrategy in log4j2 in Java

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have one concern in log4j2. In the below appender definition, default rollover strategy is employed as shown below:

```
 <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
```

I need to access the value of `max` in java to do some customizations. Please help me about how this value can be retrieved. I can get the appender from the logger but I am not aware about how to get the `max` value of `DefaultRolloverStrategy` defined within this appender.

```
<RollingFile name="TEST_FILE" fileName="${sys:LOGS}/test.log" filePattern="${sys:LOGS}/test.log.%i" append="true">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d %-5p [%c{1}] [CustomData: %data] [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 KB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
        <Filters>
            <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG"/>
                <ThresholdFilter level="OFF" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>              
        </Filters>
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34692415/1446916 Log4j 2.5 has a better mechanism for cleaning up old log files: a customizable Delete action that is triggered on rollover. Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this by using the below code snippet.

int maxBackupIndex = ((DefaultRolloverStrategy)((RollingFileAppender) app).getManager().getRolloverStrategy()).getMaxIndex();