# Tomcat log4j.xml and log4j2.xml rolling logs configured to delete old

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I have an application and depending on the version it uses `log4j.xml` and `log4j2.xml`.
I have tried many ways but I cannot seem to have it only keep 30 Days of logs it continues to collect. Below are my setup in each version, any help is greatly appreciated.

`log4j2.xml`

```
<RollingFile name="appLog"> 
  <FileName>${sys:app.root}/path/to/aapplication/app.log</FileName> 
  <FilePattern>${sys:app.root}/path/to/aapplication/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FilePattern> 
  <PatternLayout> 
    <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern> 
  </PatternLayout> 
  <Policies> 
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" /> 
  </Policies> 
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30" /> 
</RollingFile>
```

`log4j.xml`

```
<appender name="appLog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="File" value="${sys:app.root}/path/to/aapplication/app.log" /> 
    <param name="Append" value="true" /> 
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"/> 
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%-5p][%d] - [%m]%n" /> 
    </layout> 
</appender>
```

Comment: In your first file, there's a double quote missing at the end of that line: `<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true />`

Comment: Thanks completely missed that. Was correct in the xml, I must have done something in the copy over.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete older rolled over log4j2 logs, keeping up to 10 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692415/how-to-delete-older-rolled-over-log4j2-logs-keeping-up-to-10-files)

Comment: Basically `DefaultRolloverStrategy`, when applied to files with date patterns, limits itself to rename the current file.